# Building Organizations with Subgroups

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I'm struggling with a database design issue, and it's kind of a long winded one:

My website will have an unlimited number of organizations users they can join, subgroups under those organizations, and finally specific profiles for those subgroups.  Subgroups within the same organization will be able to borrow and make changes to profiles from each other.  Users will generate the organizations, the subgroups, and profiles.

I can draw it out, make the flow sensible on paper.  When it comes to actually putting it to either SQL I'm lost.  The majority of the help guides out there assumes static groups so a simple primary and foreign key set up can refer back to the right information.  Mine has too much dynamic information for most of these to outright work as I understand it.

Most writers say stay away from dynamically generated tables, but that's where my instinct takes me.  Another idea I had was 3 massive tables one for all Organizations, Groups, and Profiles.

So is there a better way to go about this?  Or are there any good documents I should read up on to help me translate from drawing to actual code?

I have some experience with both SQL and MongoDB if that helps explain things.

Comment: Why is this tagged both MySQL and MongoDB -- two very different systems?  Your idea of three "massive" tables would seem to be the right approach.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was missing something with either one that could make this easier.  Currently I'm at initial design phase so I have the room to go either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about MongoDB(NoSQL), but from the SQL standpoint, here is my opinion.

As far as your schema goes, Most of the time when your "instinct" indicates that :- *Only a "Dynamic Tables" solution is your best bet*, for some problem that you are working on.

Remember there is a high chance that, **that** very problem can be solved by multiple static tables with different relationships. (By Static I mean the ones which you have created yourself as a developer.)

Also I'd like to mention that, I too myself in my initial days always thought of problem solving the similar way, but then I started understanding the principles  and how exactly the databases work.

**Back To Your Problem:-** 
If your organisation hirerchy consists of three major types of objects/levels, viz. Organizations, Groups, and Profiles then I'd suggest that you go with the 3 tables with correct relationships, which any SQL engine is quiet efficient at handling, in comparison to creating tables at runtime.

Now if the hierarchy is dynamic like say, An organisation can contain many groups which in turn shall contain profiles which again shall/can contain other organisations and so on.... Then you may want to look at Recursive structure with SQL(Recursion). (Just do a google search there are a lot of articles about that.)

Comment: It doesn't need to be recursive, stand up to three layers.  I attempted to model this out and I think I need at least 3 additional static tables, for memberships of the Organizational and Subgroups, and one for Organization's Subgroups.  

The end profile would have foreign keys for the Organization and Subgroup it belongs to, as well as the primary User on the account.  But if there are multiple users who can have a secondary status on an account, would I need to make another table?  Or anything else that could help that I'm missing?

Comment: **"if there are multiple users who can have a secondary status on an account"** since the `accounts` can have multiple users(one primary and other secondary) you can always create that one to many relation on a new table named `userstatus` there the columns would be `id , userid, accountid, type` where the type can be boolean, 0 representing secondary and 1 representing primary.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me model my logic so I can build it with either database structure we end up using!

Comment: Glad my solution helped you is some way :)